# MATLAB - hold on for subplot between different figures (Solved, but may have issues on Version R2012a)

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, subplot

I'm new to MATLAB, and I've been searching around for what I'm trying to do, but the results don't fit quite well.

I'm graphing plots of variations of transfer functions, the code I've done is below:

```
omega = 3;
K = omega * omega;

for zeta = 0.1:0.1:2
    sys = tf(K,[1 2*zeta*omega omega]);
    figure();
    subplot(1,2,1);
    step(sys);
    title('Step response');

    [num,den] = tfdata(sys, 'v');
    disp(den);
    r = roots(den);
    subplot(1,2,2);
    %hold (subplot(1,2,2), 'on');
    plot(real(r), imag(r), 'o');
    title('Pole Locations in Complex Plane');
end
```

Each time the loop runs, it will create a new figure. The first subplot should be unique for every figure, but the second subplot should plot the accumulation of all points (roots of denominator of all transfer functions) from figures before it. I tried to use `hold (subplot(1,2,2), 'on');` to keep the second subplot, but it didn't work. My thought is that because the subplots are different figures, `hold on` cannot be used.

How can I solve this problem? Any help will be great.

Comment: So do you want your second subplot to also have the first plot under the new plot? I mean overlap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution is to use 'Tag' in your subplot. I am using your code to edit:

```
omega = 3;
K = omega * omega;

for zeta = 0.1:0.1:2
    sys = tf(K,[1 2*zeta*omega omega]);
    figure();
    sb = subplot(1,2,1);
    set(sb, 'Tag', 'daddy')  % Something to tag with -  memorable
    step(sys);
    title('Step response');

    [num,den] = tfdata(sys, 'v');
    disp(den);
    r = roots(den);

    sb = subplot(1,2,2);
    set(sb, 'Tag', 'child')
    sb = findobj('Tag','child'); % Use MATLAB methods to find your tagged obj

    set(sb,'NextPlot','add'); % set 'NextPlot' property to 'add'

    plot(real(r), imag(r), 'o');
    title('Pole Locations in Complex Plane');
end
```

DOes this work for you? btw. This is also in [MATLAB central](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/99127-why-does-the-hold-on-command-not-work-when-i-try-to-update-figures-with-subplots). You should use that too.

Comment: @am304          Thanks for the +1 :P. I got it off MATLAB but just tried to explain. It's really dodgy how you can do this!!

Comment: It didn't work for me, probably because I'm using 2012 version of MATLAB on my laptop. It's very helpful though! I'm going to look into those functions and try the code soon on my school computer.

Comment: @user3763711     Thanks for this update! Could you please update the question title to include version number so that we know that version may be the issue.